# Node util.inherits and this issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, this, bind

I am trying to resolve a 'this problem' in a Node server. If I don't replace the following `worker.stuff` with `worker.stuff.bind(worker)` it doesn't work.

**Is there a way to add the `bind` in the Worker Class itself?** Using it every time I call the function is boring.

Here is the server:

```
var app = require("express")()
    , Worker = require('./worker')
    , worker = new Worker();

app.get("/stuff", worker.stuff);

worker.on('done', function () {
    console.log('done')
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the worker:

```
function Worker(options) {}

require('util').inherits(Worker, require('events').EventEmitter);

Worker.prototype.stuff = function (req, res) {
    this.emit('done');
    res.send();
}

module.exports = Worker;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701987/javascript-function-binding-this-keyword-is-lost-after-assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I can think of:

```
function Worker(options) {
    var self = this;

    this.stuff = function (req, res) {
        self.emit('done');
        res.send();
    }
}

require('util').inherits(Worker, require('events').EventEmitter);

module.exports = Worker;
```

Define all your methods inside the constructor and refer to the closured `self` instead of `this`.

I'd probably bite the bullet and use `bind` as necessary.

Comment: This code is ok, but, the `stuff` method is not in the Worker's prototype, no?

Comment: No, it isn't in the prototype.

Comment: Any idea to have both? Binding this and adding methods to the prototype? Thanks.