# Why does `(object.fun = object.fun)() use `window` but (object.fun)() uses `object` for `this`?

Tags: javascript

In the book "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers" 3rd edition, it said that:

```
var name = "The window";

var object = {
    name: "My object",

    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

object.getName();   //"My object"
(object.getName)(); //"My object"
(object.getName = object.getName)(); //"The window"
```

The question is why `(object.getName)();`  will print `"My object"` instead of `"The window"` like the third?

I think `object.getName` shall return a pointer to the function, just like the third one. The `this` shall point to the global object, which is `window` in web browser. Therefore it shall print the `"The window"`. However it seems that `object.getName` returns `object.getName` itself. Why?

Comment: That's a JavaScript function expression.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: That's not a dupe. WenqiMa is asking why the second of the 3 invocations gives "My object" instead of "The window" like the third one does.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think this is a duplicate. The title makes it look like one but the actual question asked by OP is different.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert. I know there are many questions to the instance function, but here in parentheses it is the method of a object. I cannot figure out the result.

Comment: Ah... Now I understand. @WenqiMa...

Comment: Thanks for the edit @squint...

Comment: The result of the assignment operator (`=`) is the set value. The expression returns the function itself _after_ reassigning it to the object. As the `this` value is determined by how a function is called the `this` value in that case refers the to global object.

Comment: Thanks @squint. That is exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @Vohuman - Why not post that as an answer? Do it fast, before some chump copies your comment.

Comment: It does seem strange that the one would retain its object reference and the other does not, but as @Vohuman stated, the method isn't truly "detached" from the object until the assignment, at which point you'd be invoking the method *without* the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more confusing part is actually about the 3rd example, but let me answer your specific question about the second example:

> The question is why `(object.getName)();` will print `"My object"` instead of `"The window"` like the third?

Think of how JavaScript resolves the pieces of your code:

```
object // This is the reference to the object you've made. No surprises here

object.getName // A reference to the function `getName`, with `this` bound to `object`
(object.getName) // This is the same thing as #2. The parens aren't important here

object.getName(); // Invoking the function, as you normally would
(object.getName)(); // Strange syntax, but just invoking the function all the same
```

#### But what about when "The window" gets printed?

This is the more confusing part.

```
(object.getName = object.getName)(); // Things start to go strange here
```

This is partly because of the assignment (`=`) operator, and it is because [JavaScript function binding (this keyword) is lost after assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701987/javascript-function-binding-this-keyword-is-lost-after-assignment).

When you reference the function object and then assign that reference to anything, it is passed as a "value type" instead of a "reference type". This drops the `this` pointer, unless you bind it back manually. See [the documentation for the `this` keyword, when calling a function as an object method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method):

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

What this means may become a little more clear by modifying your example:

```
var name = "The window";

var object = {
    name: "My object",

    getName: function() {
        console.log(this); // See what `this` is bound to
        return this.name;
    }
}

object.getName(); // Prints `Object {name: "My object"}`
(object.getName)(); // Also prints `Object {name: "My object"}`
var func = object.getName;
func(); // Prints `Window`
(object.getName = object.getName)(); // Also prints `Window`
```

You'll notice the same behavior if you try to pass the function as a callback to some other function:

```
function test(callback) {
    callback();
}

test(object.getName); // Prints `Window`
```

However, if the base object is still bound *while you are calling it*, then you will see the normal object behavior:

```
function test(obj) {
    obj.getName();
}

test(object); // Prints `Object {name: "My object"}`
```

---

#### Other interesting or useful behavior

Doing the assignment doesn't break the original object. Even if you've gotten `this` mangled on some other reference, `object` is still intact:

```
(object.getName = object.getName)(); // Prints `Window`
object.getName(); // Prints `Object {name: "My object"}`. It didn't break
```

If you assign the function reference back to a different property on the object, you'll see that `this` gets assigned correctly on the new property. This is because the important part is whether you are specifying the base object while you are calling the function:

```
var temp = object.getName;
temp(); // Prints `Window`
object.somethingElse = temp;
object.somethingElse(); // Prints `Object {name: "My object"}`. `this` is correctly bound
```

If you pull a function off an object and stick it on a totally different object then it will still work, but `this` will be bound to the new object.

[Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) rely on this behavior in order to do their magic.

```
var basketball = {
    name: "Sports equipment?!",
}

basketball.doStuff = object.getName;
basketball.doStuff(); // Prints `Object {name: "Sports equipment?!"}`
```

If for some reason you get a reference to your function without `this` being bound, you can still correct it, as long as you have a reference to the original object:

```
var temp = object.getName;
temp(); // Prints `Window`
var temp2 = temp.bind(object);
temp2(); // Prints `Object {name: "My object"}` because you bound `this`
temp.apply(object); // Also prints `Object {name: "My object"}`
```

Comment: Thanks @Merlyn. now my question is why object.getName is the same thing as (object.getName). I thought (object.getName)() is sth like: var gn = object.getName; gn();

Comment: @WenqiMa It's "sort of" like it, but strange things happen to javascript object methods when they are on the right hand side of an assignment operator. As soon as you do `... = object.getName`, the `this` gets stripped off. Putting it in parentheses doesn't do this, just putting it on the right-hand side of an assignment operator. The reasons for this are detailed in the link I mentioned in the middle - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701987/javascript-function-binding-this-keyword-is-lost-after-assignment

Comment: In reality it is more about how you call the function than the assignment operator (whether you're calling the function on a "reference type", which has a `this` or a "value type", which doesn't), but due to the design of the language, the assignment operator is where you'll start to notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the assignment operator (`=`) is the set value. Consider this example:

```
> var num;
> num = 3;
< 3 // the returned value of the assignment
```

The expression returns the function itself *after reassigning it to the object*. As the `this` value is determined by how a function is called the `this` value in that case refers the to global object. In the second snippet (`(object.getName)();`) the function is called as a member of the `object` object and this is why the `this` refers to the `object`.

Comment: short and correct. The return value of the `=` operator being the unbound function is what causes the confusion here.