# Put function that returns promise in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise, react-redux

I'll explain why I want to do this later. 
Here is the problem. I have a function that returns a promise like below:

```
const testFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() >  0.5) {
        resolve('succeeded');
      } else {
        reject('failed');
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

As expected, I can invoke it like this just fine:

```
testFunc()
  .then((result) => console.log(result)) // 'succeeded'
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // 'failed'
```

Or assign it to a variable and call it like this

```
const testFuncVar = testFunc;
testFuncVar()
  .then((result) => console.log(result)) // 'succeeded'
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // 'failed'
```

These are all expected. However, once I put the function in redux state, then invoke it from there, it doesn't work anymore. Here is what I did (grossly simplified).

```
const initialState = {testFunc: testFunc};
// redux reducer, action creator, etc.
...
...
// somewhere later. Here I'm using redux-thunk to access redux state
function testFunInState() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {testFunc} = getState();
    // this is not working
    testFunc()
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
}
```

The error I got was `_promise2 is not defined`. Note that the variable name `_promise2` should be from babel transpiler. If I `console.log(state.testFunc)` or `console.log(testFunc)`, I got:

```
testFunc() {
  return new _promise2.default(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      resolve('succeeded');
    } else {
      reject('failed');
    }
  });
}
```

So somehow the `Promise` object got lost whenever the function is put in redux state?

But I did find a workaround. If I change the function to

```
const testFunc = (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (Math.random() >  0.5) {
      resolve('succeeded');
    } else {
      reject('failed');
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

And call it with `resolve` and `reject` passed in as parameters, then I'm good.

```
// this works
new Promise((resolve, reject) => state.testFunc(resolve, reject))
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I'm wondering why a function that returns promise doesn't work once it's put in redux store, but one without returning promise works?

Now onto why I want to do it this way. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a job queue that periodically dispatch some async actions, and depending on the result (resolve or reject), does something else (like retry, or send out notification). I want to dynamically add/remove jobs to and from the queue, therefore it's hard to have a reducer that can handle all possible actions. It feels like this is a reasonable way to approach it. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: That's confusing, especially the error as there doesn't seem to be a `_promise2` ... anything .. in the posted code ?

Comment: I highly suspect the bug you encountered is not shown in this snippet. It doesn't matter what the function returns, you're just storing a reference to it in the store.

Comment: @adeneo `_promise2` should be from bable transpiler. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Post the reducer code where you stamp the promise func on `state`

Comment: @lux, I'm using redux-thunk to access `testFunc` in state. I've made additional edit to the original question. 
@AlexG, I had the same understanding that what gets returned doesn't matter, as I'm just storing a reference to the function. But somehow whenever I have `new Promise` in the function, it stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit more digging, I finally figured that the problem really has nothing to do with redux or promise. It's simply because they way `testFunc` getting added to redux state through assignment to `initialState` object literal. When it's done this way, the binding is lost, hence the `_promise2 is undefined` error. Actually if I add `testFunc` to redux state dynamically (e.g. via action creator and reducer), the binding got preserved and everything works just fine. Here is a more detail explanation of the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/2702028/4401488.

Just for reference, here is the code for adding `testFunc` to redux state via reducer

```
const initialState = {};
// redux reducer
export default function jobReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_JOB:
      return {job: action.job};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// action creator
export function addJob(job) {
  return {
    type: ADD_JOB,
    job: job
  };
}
...
// add testFunc to redux state via action creator,
// I'm using redux-thunk here to access dispatch
function addTestFun() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addJob(testFunc));
  };
}
...
// invocation of testFunc. Here I'm using redux-thunk to access redux state
function testFunInState() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {testFunc} = getState();
    // Now this is working
    testFunc()
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use middleware with Redux such as [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Then write your action like so:

```
const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';

function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}

function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with `dispatch`
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

You could also try using [Redux-Promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise)

Comment: I am using redux thunk. But in this case, my goal is not to dispatch a series async actions. Instead, I want to dynamically add or remove thunks (functions that return promises) to redux state, and have a scheduler dispatch them periodically.

Comment: The store is meant to track application state / data, not to house functions. Could you have a data structure in your store that references the thunks and then have  the scheduler call them based on what's in your store?