# Mutating a RxJS observable with variable mutators - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I made a service that gets some userdata from a remote source. The service a method for getting multiple users, and one for getting a specific user.
The observables returned from the two methonds get .pipe(ed) thru a map() to be able to mutate the user-objects before they get consumed.

What I want is to only define the mutators once, for both the multiple users stream and the single users stream, but I run into scope problems with my current approach.

Be aware that I call users "heroes". This is a design aspect.
Following are the corresponding methods from my HeroService class:

```
export class HeroService {
  // [...]

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.addSkillsToHero)),
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.splitName))
    );
  }

  getHero(id): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.get<Hero>(this.heroesUrl + "/" + id).pipe(
      map((hero: Hero) => this.addSkillsToHero(hero)),
      map((hero: Hero) => this.splitName(hero))
    );
  }

  private mutateHeroes(heroes: Hero[], mutator) {
    heroes.forEach((hero: Hero) => {
      hero = mutator(hero);
    });
    return heroes;
  }

  private splitName(hero: Hero) {
    let heroNames: string[] = hero.name.split(" ");

    hero.firstname = heroNames.splice(0, 1).join(" ");
    hero.lastname = heroNames.splice(heroNames.length - 1, 1).join(" ");
    hero.middlename = heroNames.join(" ");

    return hero;
  }

  private addSkillsToHero(hero: Hero) {
    hero.skills = this.getSkills(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
    return hero;
  }

  private getSkills(count: number): string[] {
    let skills: string[] = [];
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      skills.push(this.getRandomSkill());
    }

    return skills;
  }

  private getRandomSkill(): string {
    return SKILL_TAGS[Math.floor(Math.random() * SKILL_TAGS.length)];
  }
  // [...]
}
```

The catchError() of the Observable(s) return: `Cannot read property 'getSkills' of undefined`
I am suspecting that the mutator does not get called inside the class scope, and cant be found therefore.

How would I do such a thing in JS?

The whole project can be inspected at:

- https://github.com/maxbethke/myFirstAngularApp
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rfghml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.addSkillsToHero)),
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.splitName))
    );
  }
```

Passing `this.addSkillsToHero` as this, doesn't keep the `this` reference. You are passing a reference to a function, `this` is determined at call time. You either need to bind that function to the `this` you need, or use an arrow function which does the capturing of `this` for you. You can find more details here: [JavaScript function binding (this keyword) is lost after assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701987/javascript-function-binding-this-keyword-is-lost-after-assignment) or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

You can try it like:

```
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.addSkillsToHero.bind(this))),
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, this.splitName.bind(this)))
    );
  }
```

or using arrow functions:

```
 getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, h => this.addSkillsToHero(h))),
      map((heroes: Hero[]) => this.mutateHeroes(heroes, h => this.splitName(h)))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for. I would be interested in a technical explanation, why wrapping it into another function keeps the scope tho.

Comment: @DumperJumper added some more details.

Answer (score 0):

## Arrow Functions (Lamdas) to the Rescue

As already mentioned, your issue comes down to how a function's context (`this`) is decided. This is something that is done at run-time.

To expand on another answer given here, you can define a function with its context (`this`) already bound. The trick is to invoke the function early and work with a partially applied version of that function. One way to do that is with `bind`.

```js
const functionName = (function (args){
  /* Some code */
  return /*something*/
}).bind(this);
```

That's kinda ugly, so JavaScript has arrow functions that do much the same thing.

```js
const functionName = (args) => {
  /* Some code */
  return /*something*/
}
```

That's much prettier. Even better is that <s>one-line</s> single-expression Lamdas have an implicit return:

```js
const functionName = (args) => {
  return /*something*/;
}
// Is the same as
const functionName = (args) => /*something*/;
```

Normal functions are given a context when invoked. Arrow functions always bind the scope they're defined in as their context. If you're not using Javascript's prototypal inheritance, there's generally not much reason that a function's context would need to change from the scope it is defined in.

I find you can really neaten up your code if you're willing to lean into this knowledge a bit.

Here's how I would write your HeroService class entirely with arrow functions. If this is the best way to do this is up for debate. Certainly, this approach allows for more of a declarative/functional style. In practice, a mix of the two gets you the best of both worlds.

```js
export class HeroService {
  // [...]

  public getHeroes = (): Observable<Hero[]> =>
    this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map(this.mutateHeroes(this.addSkillsToHero)),
      map(this.mutateHeroes(this.splitName))
    );

  public getHero = (id): Observable<Hero> => 
    this.http.get<Hero>(this.heroesUrl + "/" + id).pipe(
      map(this.addSkillsToHero),
      map(this.splitName)
    );

  private mutateHeroes = transformer => 
    (heroes: Hero[]) => heroes.map(transformer);

  private splitName = (hero: Hero) => {
    let heroNames: string[] = hero.name.split(" "); 
    return ({
      ...hero,
      firstName: heroNames.splice(0, 1).join(" "),
      lastname: heroNames.splice(heroNames.length - 1, 1).join(" "),
      middlename: heroNames.join(" ")
    });
  }

  private addSkillsToHero = (hero: Hero) => ({
    ...hero, skills: this.getSkills(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10))
  });

  private getSkills = (count: number): string[] => 
    Array.from({length: count}).map(this.getRandomSkill);

  private getRandomSkill = (): string => 
    SKILL_TAGS[Math.floor(Math.random() * SKILL_TAGS.length)];
  
  // [...]
}
```

## Extra: Composing Functions

A cool property of a properly implemented map function (does not matter if you're mapping over arrays or streams) is that:

```js
map(x => f(g(x))) 
  === 
map(g).map(f)
```

This tells us that if we compose `addSkillsToHero`, and `splitName` then you can do this with a single `map` instead of two. RxJS streams are actually transducers, so they do this for you (in a way), but array map doesn't so you can gain some marginal performance through compositions as well (You iterate through your array only once!).

Normally you'd you a library like Ramda/Redux/Lodash/etc and you could write something like

```js
private addSkillsAndSplitName = 
  compose(this.addSkillsToHero, this.splitName);
```

But composing two functions is pretty easy with vanilla JavaScript too.

```js
private addSkillsAndSplitName = 
  hero => this.addSkillsToHero(this.splitName(hero))
```

Then you can use this new function like this:

```js
export class HeroService {
  // [...]

  public getHeroes = (): Observable<Hero[]> =>
    this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map(this.mutateHeroes(this.addSkillsAndSplitName))
    );

  public getHero = (id): Observable<Hero> => 
    this.http.get<Hero>(this.heroesUrl + "/" + id).pipe(
      map(this.addSkillsAndSplitName)
    );
```

And you haven't taken a hit on testability, flexibility, or separation of concerns as the functionality still exists in separate functions.